# UploadStringAsync won't work in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, async-await

I'm new in C# and I'd like to crate library for my RESTlike API in Windows Phone application.

My api structure is sort of

```
http://mysiteurl/api/method_name.json
```

So I would like to call api with (method_name, params) and return specified class.

When I launch this code on my Windows Phone 8.1 program freeze and nothing happens. Also I can see anything on serverside (any call)

API.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SampleProg.Model;

namespace SampleProg.Lib
{
    public class Api
    {
        public async Task<VersionClass> versionInfo()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("versionInfo()");
            var result = await this.Post<VersionClass>("version", "{}", null);
            Debug.WriteLine(result);
            return result;
        }

        public async Task<TReturnType> Post<TReturnType>(string methodName, string data, Dictionary<string, string> headers)
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();

            webClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
            webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            var uri = new Uri(String.Format("http://mysiteurl/api/{0}.json", methodName));

            if (headers != null)
            {
                foreach (var key in headers.Keys)
                {
                    webClient.Headers[key] = headers[key];
                }
            }

            return await Post<TReturnType>(webClient, uri, data);
        }

        private async Task<TReturnType> Post<TReturnType>(WebClient webClient, Uri uri, string jsonData)
        {
            TReturnType returnObject = default(TReturnType);

            var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<TReturnType>();

            webClient.UploadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                var result = e.Result;

                try
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(result);
                    returnObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TReturnType>(result);

                    taskCompletionSource.SetResult(returnObject);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var newEx = new Exception(
                      string.Format("Failed to deserialize server response: {0}", result), ex);
                    taskCompletionSource.SetException(newEx);
                }
            };

            webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", jsonData);

            return await taskCompletionSource.Task;
        }

    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs (I call this from public App() {} ):

```
var api = new Api();
var apiTask = api.versionInfo();
VersionClass version = (VersionClass)apiTask.Result;
Debug.WriteLine(version.num);
```

VersionClass.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SampleProg.Model
{
    public class VersionClass
    {
        [JsonProperty("version")]
        public int num { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Could you tell me what is wrong? I use this code (at bottom) http://sandor68.rssing.com/chan-11557297/all_p1.html as base

Comment: Are you able to use [UploadStringTaskAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193920(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `UploadStringAsync`? I'd also guess you are deadlocking because you are calling `.Result` on your task rather than awaiting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
VersionClass version = (VersionClass) apiTask.Result;
```

Is deadlocking your app.

What's happening is the `SynchronizationContext` is trying to marshal control back to the `UI thread` after the `await` inside your inner method.

You should **always** `await` on a `Task`:

```
VersionClass version = (VersionClass) await apiTask;
```

Also, be aware that your wrapping of `UploadStringAsync` which returns a `Task` is already made for you OOTB via [`WebClient.UploadStringTaskAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193920(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Edit**

If you choose to continue your version of `Post`, you should not `await` on the returned `Task`, you should let the user do that, and unregister the handler from the `UploadStringCompleted`:

```
private async Task<TReturnType> Post<TReturnType>(WebClient webClient, Uri uri, string jsonData)
{
    TReturnType returnObject = default(TReturnType);

    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<TReturnType>();

    UploadStringCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (s, e) =>
    {
        webClient.UploadStringCompleted -= handler;

        var result = e.Result;

        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(result);
            returnObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TReturnType>(result);

            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(returnObject);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var newEx = new Exception(
              string.Format("Failed to deserialize server response: {0}", result), ex);
            taskCompletionSource.SetException(newEx);
        }
    };

    webClient.UploadStringCompleted += handler;

    webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", jsonData);

    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

Comment: Int this way how to unregister handler properly? I got "Cannot assign anonymous method to an implicitly-typed local variable." error if I try to do it like in example code.